# How to connect Raspberry Pi to my linux PC?

Tags: linux, pi-1

I haven't done anything to my Raspberry Pi or my computer except for putting the docker image onto the SD card.

I tried looking for how to do this without a display but couldn't find how anywhere. They all seemed to have a step that I needed to do to get there, but I didn't know what. How would I go about doing this?

I have:

- rpi1 2011.12
- SD card with docker image on it
- All wires required

Comment: What docker image. And are you trying to use a docker image instead of an OS like Raspbian on your Pi?

Comment: Is there any reason why you have no attached display? I suggest to start with a Raspi connected to a display and keyboard first. 

If you have a docker image (which image?) started on your Raspberyy (how do you do this?) how do you try to connect to the image?

Comment: @framp I used the Raspbian docker image. I added it using the instructions...
I can't use a display because i don't have one.

Comment: @12944qwerty Please provide a link to the docker image you downloaded and the instructions you followed.

Comment: @framp I used [the first download](https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/raspbian/) and followed [these instructions](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/installation/installing-images/linux.md)

Answer (score 1):

You don't use a docker image. It's just a plain Raspbian image you use.

There is one important step you have to execute when you copied the image on the SD card: Enable ssh access. See [Enable SSH on a headless Raspberry Pi](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/remote-access/ssh/)

Comment: hmm, i must have confused the images